# What was the goal of Nicolas de Larmessin etched pictures of artisans?

Tags: europe, food

Nicolas de Larmessin created etched pictures of many different artisans and skilled laborers. Does anyone know what the goal of this artwork was? They are very interesting and detailed images, but I don't understand their role or intended audience.

Thanks

[Habit de caffetier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXRET.jpg)

**To See some more of his works!**

http://www.retronaut.com/2012/07/costumes-by-nicolas-de-larmessin-ii-1700/

Answer (score 2):

The pictures to which you refer are not exactly pictures of artisans and skilled laborers. They are rather images of the craft itself. The pictures are of people dressed in the tools and produce of one craft. As such, the pastry-baker is shown dressed in pastries and an oven.

They are likely intended to be funny.

http://www.laboiteverte.fr/costumes-grotesques-et-metiers-de-nicolas-de-larmessin/